# System.exit(status),>> This method never returns normally. What does it means

Tags: java, jvm

I know in we can terminate JVM with System.exit(), but in java doc ,they written as >>

"**This method never returns normally.**". What does it means?

Comment: Once you call it, it won't return...So any code beyond this point won't be executed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means program stops its execution from that line of code and it will not execute return statement and will even not call finally block

Answer (score 1):

The documented purpose of this method is to stop the application.

Notes:

- even finally blocks are prevented from executing.
- the shutdown hooks are still run.

I assume the question is;

> When does System.exit(n) return?

When you have an application server, running multiple applications, you don't want one to bring down the whole JVM.  In this situation you typically have a SecurityManager which prevents a number of operations esp System.exit().  In this situation, a SecurityException can be thrown, or the JVM shuts down the specific application being run.

Comment: I think the term “*normally*” should be more emphasized here. Indeed, a `SecurityManager` might prevent the termination and cause `System.exit(…)` to throw a `SecurityException` (not an `Error`) which implies that `System.exit(…)` **can** complete, but not complete *normally*. And in case of an exception being thrown, `finally` block *are* executed…

Answer (score 0):

After the call `System.exit()` your application will terminate immediately not executing and code following the `exit()` statement. Look at this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("about to exit");
    System.exit(1);
    System.out.println("returned normally");
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
about to exit
```

The second statement `System.out.println("returned normally")` got never called.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the next line of code after System.exit won't be executed (because the JVM was shut down before getting there).

Answer (score 0):

It means the program doesn't cleanly return from where it us executing.  An exception thrown is also a case where the program doesn't 'cleanly' return.. As in executing through the end. Exit call abruptly terminates the execution flow.

Comment: This is much different from an exception, though. Exceptions can be caught, the call stack gets unrolled nicely, finally blocks are executed, etc. None of that happens with `System.exit(code);`

Comment: Yes. I was just talking about when an exception is consciously thrown. Agreed that we have some control in this case but still the code that is executing can't be said it returned cleanly.